# Sixth root of -64 using Euler's formula and De Moivre's theorem

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

I am attempting to solve:
$$(-64)^{\frac{1}{6}}$$
Using the relation:
$$a+bi=re^{i(\tan^{-1}(\frac{b}{a})+2\pi n)}$$
And then applying De Moivre's theorem:
$$(a+bi)^{\frac{1}{x}}=(re^{i(\tan^{-1}(\frac{b}{a})+2\pi n)})^{\frac{1}{x}}$$
$$...=r^{\frac{1}{x}}e^{i(\frac{\tan^{-1}(\frac{b}{a})}{x}+\frac{2\pi n}{x})}$$
$$...=64^{\frac{1}{6}}e^{i(\frac{\tan^{-1}(\frac{0}{64})}{6}+\frac{2\pi n}{6})}$$
$$...=2e^{i(\frac{\pi n}{3})}$$
Now! When $n=0$ (the first case in using this strategy), then we get
$$2e^{0i}$$
Which should be, drumroll, $2$. Obviously though, $2$ is not a sixth root of $-64$. So where did this methodology go wrong?

Comment: Where is $-64$ in the complex plane? It lies on the negative real exis. It's principle argument is $\pi$, not zero.

Comment: just find one sixth root, say a. they the rest you can place the remaining five on the circle centered at the origin radius $|a|$ at equal distance from each other(cyclotomic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem arises from assuming that the principal argument of a complex number $\text{a + ib}$ is equal to $\arctan{\frac{b}{a}}$.

This would assume your argument to be 0, when in fact it is equal to $\pi$.

Try your calculations again using this.